# addSubview on cellForItemAtIndexPath issue in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView with custom cells.
I am trying to add dynamic labels in each cell, but they are only added to the last cell shown. If i make scroll, labels disappear of that cell and appear in the new cell shown.
The number and text of labels will be achieved with a web service.
This is my cellForItemAtIndexPath function:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UndatedCell
        cell.titleLabel.text = "Sacar al perro"
        cell.locationLabel.text = "Casa"

        var aux: CGFloat = 0

        for label in labelsArray {
            let labelWidht = calculateLabelWidht(label) + 20
            cell.labelsView.addSubview(label)
            label.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(cell.labelsView.leftAnchor, constant: aux).active = true
            label.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(cell.labelsView.centerYAnchor).active = true
            label.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(labelWidht).active = true

            aux = aux + labelWidht + 8
        }

        return cell
    }
```

In viewDidLoad i create the demo labels:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collectionView!.registerClass(UndatedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true

        let label1 = LabelLabel()
        label1.text = "Zara"
        labelsArray.append(label1)
        let label2 = LabelLabel()
        label2.text = "Perro"
        labelsArray.append(label2)
        let label3 = LabelLabel()
        label3.text = "Amigo"
        labelsArray.append(label3)
    }
```

Finally, this is a pic of the result:

[collectionViewPhoto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wT2O.jpg)

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: It's because cells are reused. You are using a custom `UICollectionViewCell` (`UndatedCell`), put it there, and in `prepareForReuse()`, remove the labels.

Comment: thanks Larme, it works!